# how to block .exe files in windows using powershell commands?

Tags: powershell

I want to block some of the downloaded .exe file in windows using PowerShell .Manually I done by this process https://www.wikihow.com/Block-an-Application-or-.EXE-from-Running-in-Windows but I need to do using PowerShell.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have three one liners for you

1st creates `DisallowRun` key

```
New-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\explorer\" -Name "DisallowRun" -PropertyType DWord -Value "1"
```

2nd creates `DisallowRun` container

```
New-item -Path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\explorer\" -Name "DisallowRun"
```

3rd creates key for the `.exe` file you want to block. Variable added for convinience

```
$1 = "test.exe"
New-ItemProperty -path "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\explorer\DisallowRun" -Name "1" -PropertyType String -Value "$1"
```